# How to find minima and maxima of $y=(x-1)^2(x-2)^3$?

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

There's

$$y=(x-1)^2(x-2)^3$$

I got confused due to post derivative simplification, tried to take it 4 times :/

Comment: differentiate with the product rule?  -then you will see that (x-1) and (x-2) are also factors of the derivative - does that speed it up?  you can then factor them out

Comment: @satyatech I'm pretty sure that the maximum of $-x^2$ is not $\infty$ :p

Comment: @Zubzub put x= - infinity in the function (in the qn) you will get -infinity .And for your Question the  of $$\ max(-x^2) =0 $$

Answer (score 2):

We get: $y'(x)=2(x-1)(x-2)^3+3(x-2)^2(x-1)^2$.

Is this useful ?